# VACL Matching on EtherType

Tags: switching, acl

I was attempting to use a VACL to block intra-VLAN traffic. The VACL was matching a MACL that specified an EtherType to block. I applied the VACL to a VLAN, and then plugged two PCs into the switch in the same VLAN to test the VACL. For some reason, the VACL did not block any of the specified traffic. I was wondering if anyone else could test this and see if they get similar results. I was able to block traffic with the VACL based on other criteria, such as a RACL blocking ICMP. This was tested on a 3750V2 with 12.2(55)SE5

See the configuration I was using below:

```
mac access-list extended IPv6_MACL
permit any any 0x86DD 0

vlan access-map Control_Intra_VLAN 10
match mac address IPv6_MACL
action drop

vlan access-map Control_Intra_VLAN 20
action forward

vlan filter Control_Intra_VLAN vlan-list 23
```